# how to implement borders around menuitem in SwipeMenuListView

Tags: java, android

I am using the library **com.baoyz.swipemenulistview** every thing is working good i want borders around each menu items, so that even if all menu item background is white a grey border is around the each item separating each other.

After looking into the code i have found that this can be implemented in following function of **SwipeMenuView.java**

```
private void addItem(SwipeMenuItem item, int id) {
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(item.getWidth(),
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    parent.setId(id);
    parent.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    parent.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_BEGINNING);
    parent.setLayoutParams(params);
    parent.setBackgroundDrawable(item.getBackground());
    parent.setOnClickListener(this);
    addView(parent);

    if (item.getIcon() != null) {
        parent.addView(createIcon(item));
    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getTitle())) {
        parent.addView(createTitle(item));
    }

}
```

As i am newbie for android world, i am unable to find the way to to draw border around menu item. Which function/method to look for in LinearLayout that have the capability to draw borders. Or how to draw border as shown

Ide : Android Studio 2.2.3

[image]

Link to library :
[SwipeMenuListView Github](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView)

**UPDATE**

I have added **GradeintDrawable** to the function now border is there but here i cannot pass  **item.getBackground** which will return (**Drawable**). How to set **GradientDrawable.setColor (int color);** with **item.getBackground** which will return **Drawable**;

```
private void addItem(SwipeMenuItem item, int id) {
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(item.getWidth(),
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);



    GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
    drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    drawable.setStroke(1, Color.BLACK);
    drawable.setCornerRadius(1);

    //drawable.setColor(Color.GRAY); here i have to pass item.getBackground();

     //like :
       drawable.setColor(item.getBackground); //error because getBackground is of type drawable;


    LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    parent.setId(id);
    parent.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    parent.setLayoutParams(params);
    //parent.setBackgroundDrawable(item.getBackground());
    parent.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    parent.setOnClickListener(this);
    addView(parent);

    if (item.getIcon() != null) {
        parent.addView(createIcon(item));
    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getTitle())) {
        parent.addView(createTitle(item));
    }

}
```

Comment: Im not an android developer, but in general in java swing for example, I would just add a canvas/panel with the gray fg color. And to that panel add the items I want. With a smaller width and height than the panel. Which will make it feel like it is a border. Maybe someone has better solution ?

Comment: @MrSimpleMind its seams i am near to solution. Only obstacle is how to pass Drawable to GradientDrawable.setColor